# Optimize SUM with time segment WHERE

Tags: postgresql, index

Suppose I have a table A with columns `id:int, kpi:int, created_at:datetime`. And suppose I would need to fire the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(kpi) FROM A WHERE (created_at > X AND created_at < Y)
```

This query would make a full scan. But it can be optimised with a data structure `segment tree`. It takes `O(nlog(n))` to build and `O(log(n))` to query (instead of `O(n)` in case of full scan).

The question is, is there any index or plugin for Postgres (or other SQL Database) that does this?

Comment: A b-tree index will take O(m), where m is the size of the result set.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to me. What makes you think that a "segment tree" is going to be better than a simple b-tree index on `(created_at, kpi)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why don't you simply create b-tree index on `created_at` column?

Or compound (created_at+kpi) ? In the second case all the information will be taken during the index scan and no need to read blocks from the table itself.

But if the time range between X and Y is rather big, then the optimizer might think that full table scan is cheaper anyway.

In some particular situations the clustered index may be a good solution, too. For example by days or months, so when you select values, all blocks are read from the same area that belongs to that cluster.